# alternative for Math.floor(Math.random()*10) in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

is there any alternative for Math.floor(Math.random()*10) in angular 8. Due to security issue i need to remove math.random()
someone suggested to use PRNG but i m not sure how to use that. Any help??

Comment: What "security issue"? And there's no such thing as "alternative for Math.floor(Math.random()*10) in angular 8" - this is just regular `JavaScript` code and has nothing to do with `Angular 8`. You can use whatever you'd like to generate a random number.

Comment: As @goto1 said, there isn't any security issue of `Math.random()` unless youre referring to its security when it comes to cryptography. If you're that concerned about this you can try use the Fortuna feature (Which is a PRNG but in a library) of this crypto library https://github.com/clipperz/javascript-crypto-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use - https://www.npmjs.com/package/random
It basically uses - PRNG 
Hope this will help.

Comment: i m looking for similar one. Can we use this inside our angular components?? since this one uses require('random')  ,

Comment: @VinothMarieswaran try and let us know.

Comment: in this npm doc it is mentioned like - "Supports node >= 6 and browser"
the demonstrated one uses 'require' for node implementation but you can include this as dependency in your project and then use it.